# Serializing IEnumerator<T> created using yield return

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, yield

Is there a way to serialize (using `BinaryFormatter`) the `IEnumerator<T>` that gets created when I use `yield return`s? The autogenerated class isn't marked `Serializable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler generated enumerable does not have the [Serializable] attribute applied to it, so, no, out of the box you cannot do this.

You should ask yourself, "Why am I using a yield here, and what does it mean once this object is deserialized?"

If its convenience, you can use it to fill a type that can be serialized.  If you use it to perform some heavy lifting in a lazy manner, you might want to consider changing your design to serialize/deserialize the information you need to perform that heavy lifting.

Comment: this is actually not quite right. I used to think you could not either, but you can actually use surrogates for serialization to interesting effect while still retaining fairly generic code. Check out the example code at: http://dotnet.agilekiwi.com/blog/2007/05/implementing-workflow-with-persistent.html

Answer (score 4):

Which class are you using to implement `IEnumerable<T>`?  `List<T>` should serialize OK.

Try calling `ToList()` on your collection before serializing it.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate the enumerator and serialize each instance returned.